# unique sum in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, substitution

Hi I have sheets containing the data

[image]

What I want is total paid and pending amount of each client

[image]

I have tried `={unique(F2:F),ArrayFormula(sumif(F2:F5,unique(F2:F),E2:E))}` seems like not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I3:I, QUERY({E2:F, SUBSTITUTE(G2:G, "Pending", "Unpaid")}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3"), {2, 3}, 0)*1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking for this one. I wonder if it is possible to auto collect the names from row F instead of writing it again?

Comment: @AtikRahman sure: `=INDEX(QUERY({E2:F, SUBSTITUTE(G2:G, "Pending", "Unpaid")}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3"))`